# Need help showing code results in a table

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to get this

```
for ($r = 1; $r <= 10; $r++) {
    if ($shirt_info[$r][0] != "Select One")
    {
        echo "<div class='shirtinfo'>Order $r: </div>";
        echo "<div class='shirtinfo'>Size: ".$shirt_info[$r][0]."</div>";
        echo "<div class='shirtinfo'>Price: ".$shirt_info[$r][1]."</div>";
        echo "<div class='shirtinfo'>Qty: ".$shirt_info[$r][2]."</div>";
        echo "<div class='shirtinfo'>SPE: ".$shirt_info[$r][5]."</div>";
        echo "<div class='shirtinfo'>LIA: ".$shirt_info[$r][6]."</div>";
        echo "<div class='shirtinfo'>Vendor: ".$shirt_info[$r][7]."</div>";
        echo "<div class='shirtinfo'>Style: ".$shirt_info[$r][8]."</div>";
        echo "<div class='shirtinfo'>Color: ".$shirt_info[$r][9]."</div>";
        echo "<div style='clear:both;'></div>";
    }
}
```

to show in a table and I'm not really sure how. I keep getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are showing us has an unterminated for loop. Maybe this is the syntax error.

Comment: Here is the link (http://www.redfivedesigns.com/demo/confirm.php) to the page. I'm trying to add the Order info at the top into the table with the rest of the info. The guy that wrote this left me hanging and I'm really a designer more than a programmer.

Comment: I'm not able to view the PHP of the website since it's written server-side. It *is* written on the server, isn't it? You're going to have to post it here -- http://ideone.com

Comment: Too many characters. Here is a text file www.redfivedesigns.com/confirm.txt

Comment: Sorry. I'm not familiar with PHP. You should ask the question again in more detail, (without that JS tag since this doesn't seem to be about that).

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` does not end with `}`
I would also suggest that you use `table` and not `div` if you want to display a table.

Comment: Actually it does. It just got cut off in the copy.

Comment: @Tommy: Then my answer is that there is no problem with this code. Since you say that there is syntax error, can you post it, please?

Comment: The error occurs when I try to move the code into the table. It just  says there is a syntax error on line 238. Doesn't give me a reason.

Comment: Can you copy/paste the exact error and the linke 238 or whatever the line it points out to?

Comment: Highlighting and syntax shows that you have a problem with either: `<?pre`, `?>`, `apostrophe`, or `quote`. You need to scroll up and to see where the colors change back from red to normal, for, as you see, you have a mix of php and html alltogether.

Comment: I changed all of the quotes to single quotes and that fixed the error, but now the output isn't right http://www.redfivedesigns.com/screenshot2.jpg

Comment: The output clearly shows that around the place you have the `//show the results` comment you lack `<?php` so server serves your php as html.

Comment: The <?php tag is in the file.